# Can't set a picklist default value when creating Person Account, because Person Account not visible

Tags: picklist, object, record, setup

a bit long but I'm a bit stuck. 
I have Person Accounts enabled. I'd like to set a picklist default value when someone chooses to create a new Person Account. The picklist is not a controlling field or dependent field.

If I choose Account/New Account, I'm presented with a choice of: 
Select a record type for this Account:

- ABC Business Account
- Account Type for ABC Businesses
- XYZ Business Account
- Account Type for XYZ Businesses
- XYZ Person Account
- Account Type for XYZ End Users (People)
- JKL Business Account
- Account Type for JKL Businesses
- JKL Person Account
- Account Type for JKL End Users (People)
- ABC Person Account
- Account Type for ABC End Users (People)

So the People (person) accounts are there and I have person accounts I can view. 
If I go to Setup/Objects/Accounts/Record Types... I only see the Business Account record types (and can edit them as well) but do not see any Record Type choices for my Person Accounts, which I know is where I should set my default picklist value.

Any idea how to see Person Accounts Record Type in the Setup/Object/Accounts/Record Type edit menu?

Thanks - 
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Lightning** :You go to Setup-> Object Manager.  there would be 2 entries for account. You have to select person account to set the record type picklist values. [image]

**In Classic** : You just Type person in setup search and you get record type for it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pranay!  Found it. Makes complete sense now.